# Extract value from returned json body using a shell script

Tags: json, regex, bash, shell, curl

So I have a curl statement that returns the following:

```
{
  "availabilityTimestamp" : "2015-12-29T14:20:55Z"
}
```

I store this in a variable called 'response' like as follows:
`response=$(curl...)`

I just want to extract this value from it:
2015-12-29T14:20:55Z

Any ideas how?
I will be using all this within a shell script .sh

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ & http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ & http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/yooDT4/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a JSON answer, the best practice would be to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) :

```
curl ... | jq -r '.availabilityTimestamp'
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash

    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
      response=$(curl -s -u $1 -H "Accept: application/json" "http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/v1/") | jq '.availabilityTimestamp'
      echo "$response"

    else
      echo >&2 Not given valid username
      exit 1
    fi

Comment: @Saffik put the `| jq ...` inside the `$(subshell)`, otherwise you're writing `var = value | jq ...` which makes no sense

Comment: Thanks for your help @Aaron. I am new to this website so was unaware of the rules about best answers. I have accepted your answer. :)
Thanks again.